# Why is multiply inheriting a method with different signatures ambiguous?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, ambiguous

If I inherit a function with the same name but different signatures from different base classes, an attempt to call the function generates an error claiming the call is ambiguous. The same functions in a single base class do not generate the error. Why is this?

First case, http://ideone.com/calH4Q

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Base1
{
    void Foo(double param)
    {
        cout << "Base1::Foo(double)" << endl;
    }
};

struct Base2
{
    void Foo(int param)
    {
        cout << "Base2::Foo(int)" << endl;
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base1, public Base2
{
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Derived d;
    d.Foo(1.2);
    return 1;
}

prog.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
prog.cpp:27:7: error: request for member ‘Foo’ is ambiguous
prog.cpp:14:10: error: candidates are: void Base2::Foo(int)
prog.cpp:6:10: error:                 void Base1::Foo(double)
```

Second case, no errors, http://ideone.com/mQ3J7A

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Base
{
    void Foo(double param)
    {
        cout << "Base::Foo(double)" << endl;
    }
    void Foo(int param)
    {
        cout << "Base::Foo(int)" << endl;
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Derived d;
    d.Foo(1.2);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overloading occurs between names defined in the **same** scope. When multiple bases define the same name, the definitions are in different scopes, so they don't overload. If you add two using declarations to `Derived` you can pull the two names into `Derived` and they will then overload.